# How can I pin repositories on GitHub for an organization?

Tags: github, repository

When I use a profile and customize a pinned repository, it is pinned to my profile, but I need to pin it to my organization.

How do I pin it to my organization?

Comment: In my case, repos within my orginization just showed up in my personal list, and I was able to pin them without problems. It appears however that it takes some time (more than 24 hours) for GitHub to "register" that an orginization you belong to has a new project available to pin.

Answer (score 12):

AFAIK, it should be done from your Organization account, not from your personal account.

**Update**

Steps for Enterprise GitHub, but I assume the user experience would be same for public GitHub.

1. Assuming you are the administrator for your organization, when you open profile page, you see your personal profile page.
2. On the left side, you see your profile picture, description, user name, etc. You might see an "Add Bio" as well.
3. Below that you see list of organizations (icons only) you are part of, including the one for which you are admin.
4. Now click on the Organization icon to open the organization profile.
5. By default, it opens up the Repositories Tab.
6. Below the tabs, on the far right, you would see a link to "Customize Pinned Repositories". From here, you can choose up to six **public** repositories to showcase on your organization page.

Comment: can you add the steps to do from organisation account

Comment: I've updated the answer with steps. Let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: This is a public feature, so these repos have to be public. Private repos won't show up...

Comment: Currently (2022-01) the link "Customize your pins" is on the Overview tab of the organization (for public GitHub).

Comment: Untrue, I've successfully pinned organization projects to my [own personal profile](https://github.com/aggregate1166877) for years. It seems however that I can only pin projects that have been around for some time.

Comment: @aggregate1166877, the original question is about pinning the repos at Organization level. As an admin, I've 2 "profiles" when I login into the github, (my personal profile and the organization profile). In order to pin repos at organization level, I should switch "profile" to organization profile and then pin the repos so that pinned repos show up for everyone in the organization.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following steps to manage pinned repositories for a GitHub Organization. The steps are similar to managing them for a User.

1. Login as a user with admin privileges to the Organization
2. Go to the Organization's home page, e.g. https://github.com/myorg

> Note: only public repos can be pinned.

Here you will be faced with one of 3 situations:

### Scenario 1: No org `README.md` and no pins

If you don't have a Organization `README.md` file and haven't customized your pins, you will see the following in the right sidebar with a "pin repositories" link.

[image]

Thanks to [Jespertheend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625298/jespertheend) for posting this update.

### Scenario 2: Have org `README.md` and no pins

If you have a org `README.md` (in a repo named `github.com/myorg/.github`), the link in the sidebar won't appear. An easy workaround is to temporarily rename the repo, add your pins, and rename the repo again. To do this, go into the repo's "Settings" tab and temporarily rename the repo to something like `.github_bak`. Then the sidebar link will appear so you can add your pins, and then change the repo name back to `.github`.

### Scenario 3: Have pins

For completeness, if your org already has pins, you will see a "Customize Pins" link. The link in the sidebar won't appear and won't be needed. This scenario looks like the following:

[image]

Credits: this answer includes information from [Shaleen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1891047/shaleen) and [Jespertheend](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3625298/jespertheend)

Comment: Also repo has to be public in the repo. Internal and private repos will not show up in the list.

Comment: I don't have this button with a public organisation... I am an admin and an owner. As soon as I chose my pins in the "You can create a README file or pin respositories" that button disapears and then I don't get that customize pins button when following your instructions!

Comment: @Uzer - I updated my answer to cover the scenario when you have some pins already and also when a `README.md` is present without pins. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: @Shaleen Thanks for the info! I've added it to the answer and also mentioned you in the credits at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: I actually had to click... 'You can "hide the tasks we've suggested"  on this page and bring them back later.' As the "Get started with tasks" content was preventing me from following your instructions. Add this to your answer and i think you've covered all scenarios in your answer! Its already the best so far :)

Answer (score 1):

The button seems to have been moved to the main page of an organization, but it's a bit tucked away. Under the 'View as' section there's a small 'pin repositories' link.

[image: screenshot of the 'pin repositories' link]